# How to avoid firefox's implicit tbody tag?

Tags: html, firefox, xslt, html-table

my html Page is rendered on client side using xsl and xml sent by server.
the issue i m facing is with firefox adding implicit tbody tag.
my xsl is generating few tbody tags based on some condition, firefox is nesting this tag inside its implicit tbody tag which is causing alignment issue for rows which are inside tbody tag generated by xsl.

is there any way to avoid implicit tbody tag inserted by firefox or do not allow firefox to put the tbody generated by xsl inside its own implicit tbody.

Answer (score 1):

This is down to HTML Parser.

For HTML docs the spec says that if there is a `<tr>` tag that is not inside a `<tbody>` tag then the parser needs to wrap it in a `<tbody>` tag.

If you don't want the HTML parser to make these kinds of corrections (there are many others) then you need to use a XHTML doctype so that the DOM corresponds closely to the source XML.

Also, make sure you are serving the documents using the correct MIME types.